# Should I call a method (i.e. size()) multiple times or store it (if I know the value will not change)

Tags: c++, vectors

I have a function that searches the shortest vector in a vector of vectors of pointers.

Which is a better way?

```
std::vector<std::vector<void*>> const& ways

{
   size_t i = SIZE_MAX;
   for(auto& it : ways)
   {
      if(i > it.size())
         i = it.size();
   }
}
```

OR

```
std::vector<std::vector<void*>> const& ways

{
   size_t i = SIZE_MAX;
   for(auto& it : ways)
   {
      const auto temp = it.size();
      if(i > temp)
         i = temp;
   }
}
```

As far as I can see size() does not return reference so second one is a better way, is it true?

**Also**, is there any other approach you can suggest for this method?

Comment: This is the wrong site for this type of question. You are going to get a lot more responses on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `size()` twice, like you are, almost definitely get's optimized out in any modern compiler. How you are doing it is perfectly fine. You could also do it with `std::max_element`...

```
auto max = std::max_element(ways.begin(), ways.end(), 
    [](const std::vector<void*>& left, const std::vector<void*>& right)
    { 
        return left.size() < right.size(); 
    })->size();
```

Or maybe you write the lambda as a functor instead and a little more generic, like:

```
struct ContainerSizeComparer
{
    template<typename Container>
    bool operator()(const Container& left, const Container& right)
    {
        return left.size() < right.size();
    }
};

auto max = std::max_element(ways.begin(), ways.end(), ContainerSizeComparer())->size();
```

This is one of those interesting times when hand rolling the loop is actually more readable and as small as using standard algorithms though. Unless you have a reason to write ContainerSizeComparer and use it in multiple places I would personally stick with what you were doing.

Comment: So in a multi-threaded environment there's no chance that `i.size()` can change between calls?

Comment: @DavidHarkness you need to use some kind of synchronization object to prevent that, like a mutex. As with all multithreading, it's safe to read from multiple threads at a time but not safe to write from multiple threads at the same time and not safe to read on some threads and write on others at the same time. Calling size even once might return garbage results if someone added an element at the same time as the call on another thread.

Comment: @DavidHarkness if you were saying that as an argument that the compiler shouldn't optimize it out, optimizations are never effected by the possibility of multithreading. They are effected by memory barriers like mutexes though.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I meant. I haven't used C++ in multi-threaded programs before, only other languages. Though thinking about it more, I believe it would work the same in Java.